# how to draw 2D image from RGB (565) value in C#

Tags: c#, c, image, matlab, image-processing

I have some raw data found from a camera(ov7670) in RGB (565) format. Now i want to draw a 2D image from these RGB data in C#, C,C++ or MATLAB but i have no idea how can do it. my final target is to recognize an image and show it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'recognize' an image, but, as far as displaying images, given the lack of requirements you've specified there are many ways. One I'm familiar with is [Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/), which has ways of displaying images, as well as manipulating them, such as [QImage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qimage.html). It is for c++. Manipulation wise, imagemagick or graphicsmagick are pretty decent and available for c and c++, really depends on what you want do to.

Answer (score 0):

Read the pixels 16 bits at a time. Then cast them into the following struct:

```
struct rgb {
    unsigned int red  : 5;
    unsigned int green: 6;
    unsigned int blue : 5;
}
```

You can then access each color separately. How to actually make an image from them? Use some library. That's how programming works. Never reinvent the wheel.